# ubuntu 14.10 wireless driver not working, dual boot with windows 7

Tags: wireless, dual-boot

Broadcom driver is working fine when ubuntu 14.10 is not yet installed on my system. But when I installed it alongside with Windows 7(Dual Boot) it says that "This device is not working"(Broadcom). I cant connect WIFI in ubuntu but it does in Windows 7. I search solutions in windows 7, i boot ubuntu, and it doesn't work. I boot windows again, boot ubuntu again. Thats what im doing every-time but i can't fixed it. Help me lease. Thanks :)

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Welcome to askubuntu!

Comment: 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please obtain a temporary internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working.

'Additional Drivers' is incorrect for your 14e4:4315 device.

If you have no internet capability, then do the purge step and then download this on some other computer: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7exlzch25ap6uha/b43.zip?dl=0 Transfer it on a USB or similar to your Ubuntu computer and drop it on your desktop. Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now, in the terminal:

```
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/b43
sudo cp ~/Desktop/b43/*  /lib/firmware/b43
```

Reboot.

Comment: Temporary connection? It means i'll do the coding everytime I boot ubuntu?

Comment: Ah. you mean i need temporary connection to make the code work?

Comment: It only needs to be run once.

Comment: I don't have another internet connection. All I have is wifi. Can't I do it offline?

Comment: I will edit my answer above in a few moments.

Comment: nothing happens. after inputting the code nothing happen. i reboot and still wifi is not working. :(

Comment: You did the purge step, is that correct? Then rebooted?

Comment: Yes. I did sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/b43, then it asks for password. I entered my password and it says sorry try again then i do it again.And it says 'mkdir: file exist's'. Then i do sudo cp ~/Desktop/b43/*  /lib/firmware/b43 nothing happen. I rebooted and still i can't connect to wifi.

Comment: Please tell me the result of these commands in order: sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source and next: sudo modprobe b43 and finally: dmesg | grep b43 Thanks.

Comment: sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-image-generic thermald
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bcmwl-kernel-source*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
After this operation, 3,367 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]

Comment: Go ahead and remove it and reboot.

Comment: sudo modprobe b43
Nothing appear in the terminal. But guest what after a few seconds theres a pop-up appear on my screen. It says "You are connected to Network." Haha. now solved dude. Thank you very much. Your're amazing.

Comment: I am now browsing with ubuntu. :D

Comment: Thanks. If I have a question next time please answer it again. Haha. :D
Anyways, how to mark my question [SOLVED]?